# Cannot get update to httpuv in shiny

Tags: r, shiny

I'm trying to get my shiny app to run in RStudio.

But I get this error when I run `load.packages('shiny')`:

> Error in loadNamespace(i, c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck =
>   vI[[i]]) : 
>         namespace 'httpuv' 1.4.1 is being loaded, but >= 1.4.3 is required

When I run `load.packages('httpuv')`,  version 1.4.1 is installed.

How can I get `httpuv` 1.4.3?

Comment: `if (!require("devtools")) install.packages("devtools")
devtools::install_github("rstudio/httpuv")`

Comment: OK, good, but I can't install devtools:
ERROR: dependency 'pkgload' is not available for package 'devtools'
* removing 'C:/Users/charles/Documents/R/win-library/3.3/devtools'

install.packages('pkgload') creates:
Package which is only available in source form, and may need compilation of C/C++/Fortran: ‘pkgload’
 These will not be installed